# matplotlib axis arrow tip

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to set an arrow at the end of a an axis in matplotlib.
I don't want to remove the spines and replace them with pure arrows because I need their functionalities ...

my implementation [is as slight modification of joferkington implementation](https://gist.github.com/joferkington/3845684)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arrowed_spines(ax=None, arrowLength=30, labels=('X', 'Y'), arrowStyle='<|-'):
    xlabel, ylabel = labels

    for i, spine in enumerate(['left', 'bottom']):
        # Set up the annotation parameters
        t = ax.spines[spine].get_transform()
        xy, xycoords = [1, 0], ('axes fraction', t)
        xytext, textcoords = [arrowLength, 0], ('offset points', t)
        
        # create arrowprops
        arrowprops = dict( arrowstyle=arrowStyle,
                           facecolor=ax.spines[spine].get_facecolor(), 
                           linewidth=ax.spines[spine].get_linewidth(),
                           alpha = ax.spines[spine].get_alpha(),
                           zorder=ax.spines[spine].get_zorder(),
                           linestyle = ax.spines[spine].get_linestyle() )
    
        if spine is 'bottom':
            ha, va = 'left', 'center'
            xarrow = ax.annotate(xlabel, xy, xycoords=xycoords, xytext=xytext, 
                        textcoords=textcoords, ha=ha, va='center',
                        arrowprops=arrowprops)
        else:
            ha, va = 'center', 'bottom'
            yarrow = ax.annotate(ylabel, xy[::-1], xycoords=xycoords[::-1], 
                        xytext=xytext[::-1], textcoords=textcoords[::-1], 
                        ha='center', va=va, arrowprops=arrowprops)
    return xarrow, yarrow

# plot
x = np.arange(-2., 10.0, 0.01)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.gcf().set_facecolor('white')    
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([]) 
ax.set_yticks([]) 

ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

arrowed_spines(ax)

plt.show()
```

The plot result shows a shift in the arrow as the following [image]

It seems that a shift of a point or two is consistent in the starting position and the alignment of the arrow with the spine. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Should probably include a reference to source gist: https://gist.github.com/joferkington/3845684

Comment: I recommend `ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')` instead of `ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')` so that the axes will intersect at the origin.

Comment: Here's a quick hack workaround: `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0.001))`

Answer (score 15):

There is an example showing how to get arrows as axis decorators [in the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html) using the `mpl_toolkits.axisartist` toolkit:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
    # adds arrows at the ends of each axis
    ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")

    # adds X and Y-axis from the origin
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
    # hides borders
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x*np.pi))

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

For many cases, the use of the `mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines` module is not desired. In that case one can also easily get arrow heads by using triangles as markers on the top of the spines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = 2 * np.sin(x)

rc = {"xtick.direction" : "inout", "ytick.direction" : "inout",
      "xtick.major.size" : 5, "ytick.major.size" : 5,}
with plt.rc_context(rc):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y)

    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

    # make arrows
    ax.plot((1), (0), ls="", marker=">", ms=10, color="k",
            transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
    ax.plot((0), (1), ls="", marker="^", ms=10, color="k",
            transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you wanna do things the wrong way and suffer with rescaling your plots, this is the way to go

Answer (score 9):

You could remove all spines and expand the arrows to cover the data range (found this code [here](https://3diagramsperpage.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/arrowheads-for-axis-in-matplotlib/)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arrowed_spines(fig, ax):

    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim() 
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

    # removing the default axis on all sides:
    for side in ['bottom','right','top','left']:
        ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)

    # removing the axis ticks
    plt.xticks([]) # labels 
    plt.yticks([])
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none') # tick markers
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

    # get width and height of axes object to compute 
    # matching arrowhead length and width
    dps = fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()
    bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(dps)
    width, height = bbox.width, bbox.height

    # manual arrowhead width and length
    hw = 1./20.*(ymax-ymin) 
    hl = 1./20.*(xmax-xmin)
    lw = 1. # axis line width
    ohg = 0.3 # arrow overhang

    # compute matching arrowhead length and width
    yhw = hw/(ymax-ymin)*(xmax-xmin)* height/width 
    yhl = hl/(xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)* width/height

    # draw x and y axis
    ax.arrow(xmin, 0, xmax-xmin, 0., fc='k', ec='k', lw = lw, 
             head_width=hw, head_length=hl, overhang = ohg, 
             length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False) 

    ax.arrow(0, ymin, 0., ymax-ymin, fc='k', ec='k', lw = lw, 
             head_width=yhw, head_length=yhl, overhang = ohg, 
             length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False)


# plot
x = np.arange(-2., 10.0, 0.01)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_facecolor('white') 
ax = plt.gca()

arrowed_spines(fig, ax)

plt.show()
```

[image: And this code gives ...]

Comment: I don't want to remove the spine as I still need the grid, the ticks and all other functionalities of the spines. my code is a simplified example of the things i need to do

Comment: ok. Then, I'd suggest that you tell us what you actually need to do in your question.

Comment: I need to be able to add arrows to the spine while keeping the spines and all their functionalities

Answer (score 9):

I found the most straightforward solution in [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/centered_spines_with_arrows.html). Following is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Move the left and bottom spines to x = 0 and y = 0, respectively.
ax.spines["left"].set_position(("data", 0))
ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
# Hide the top and right spines.
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

# Draw arrows (as black triangles: ">k"/"^k") at the end of the axes.  In each
# case, one of the coordinates (0) is a data coordinate (i.e., y = 0 or x = 0,
# respectively) and the other one (1) is an axes coordinate (i.e., at the very
# right/top of the axes).  Also, disable clipping (clip_on=False) as the marker
# actually spills out of the axes.
ax.plot(1, 0, ">k", transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.plot(0, 1, "^k", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)

# Some sample data.
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x*np.pi))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Here I have combined existing answers from Julien and s3b4s, and made the function more general so that you can specify the axes you wish to modify and the direction of the arrows.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arrowed_spines(
        ax,
        x_width_fraction=0.05,
        x_height_fraction=0.05,
        lw=None,
        ohg=0.3,
        locations=('bottom right', 'left up'),
        **arrow_kwargs
):
    """
    Add arrows to the requested spines
    Code originally sourced here: https://3diagramsperpage.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/arrowheads-for-axis-in-matplotlib/
    And interpreted here by @Julien Spronck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33738359/1474448
    Then corrected and adapted by me for more general applications.
    :param ax: The axis being modified
    :param x_{height,width}_fraction: The fraction of the **x** axis range used for the arrow height and width
    :param lw: Linewidth. If not supplied, default behaviour is to use the value on the current left spine.
    :param ohg: Overhang fraction for the arrow.
    :param locations: Iterable of strings, each of which has the format "<spine> <direction>". These must be orthogonal
    (e.g. "left left" will result in an error). Can specify as many valid strings as required.
    :param arrow_kwargs: Passed to ax.arrow()
    :return: Dictionary of FancyArrow objects, keyed by the location strings.
    """
    # set/override some default plotting parameters if required
    arrow_kwargs.setdefault('overhang', ohg)
    arrow_kwargs.setdefault('clip_on', False)
    arrow_kwargs.update({'length_includes_head': True})

    # axis line width
    if lw is None:
        # FIXME: does this still work if the left spine has been deleted?
        lw = ax.spines['left'].get_linewidth()

    annots = {}

    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

    # get width and height of axes object to compute
    # matching arrowhead length and width
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    dps = fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()
    bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(dps)
    width, height = bbox.width, bbox.height

    # manual arrowhead width and length
    hw = x_width_fraction * (ymax-ymin)
    hl = x_height_fraction * (xmax-xmin)

    # compute matching arrowhead length and width
    yhw = hw/(ymax-ymin)*(xmax-xmin)* height/width
    yhl = hl/(xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)* width/height

    # draw x and y axis
    for loc_str in locations:
        side, direction = loc_str.split(' ')
        assert side in {'top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'}, "Unsupported side"
        assert direction in {'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'}, "Unsupported direction"

        if side in {'bottom', 'top'}:
            if direction in {'up', 'down'}:
                raise ValueError("Only left/right arrows supported on the bottom and top")

            dy = 0
            head_width = hw
            head_length = hl

            y = ymin if side == 'bottom' else ymax

            if direction == 'right':
                x = xmin
                dx = xmax - xmin
            else:
                x = xmax
                dx = xmin - xmax

        else:
            if direction in {'left', 'right'}:
                raise ValueError("Only up/downarrows supported on the left and right")
            dx = 0
            head_width = yhw
            head_length = yhl

            x = xmin if side == 'left' else xmax

            if direction == 'up':
                y = ymin
                dy = ymax - ymin
            else:
                y = ymax
                dy = ymin - ymax


        annots[loc_str] = ax.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, fc='k', ec='k', lw = lw,
                 head_width=head_width, head_length=head_length, **arrow_kwargs)

    return annots


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(-2., 10.0, 0.01)
ax.plot(x, x**2)
fig.set_facecolor('white')

annots = arrowed_spines(ax, locations=('bottom right', 'bottom left', 'left up', 'right down'))

plt.show()
```

**Result**:

[image: Adding arrows to axes]

**Outstanding issue**: I have attempted to match the linewidth of the existing spines, but for some reason the arrows appear to have a thicker line. Experimenting with this reveals that a spine linewidth of 0.8 matches an arrow linewidth of around 0.3. Not sure why this is - currently you have to set `lw=<value>` as a manual fix.

Answer (score 3):

In order to obtain what you want, Julien's answer is enough after deleting the following section from the arrowed_spines function:

```
# removing the default axis on all sides:
for side in ['bottom','right','top','left']:
    ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)

# removing the axis ticks
plt.xticks([]) # labels 
plt.yticks([])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none') # tick markers
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
```

Spines can still be modified after the inclusion of arrows, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: You probably want to keep the top and right spines off though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in the doc here: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/recipes/centered_spines_with_arrows.html, as specified in Sadegh Bakhtiarzadeh's answer.

However, this solution is not satsfying when dispaying the grid, as it moves the edges of the grid accross the axes and the ticks labels.

You can avoid it by replacing:

```
# Move the left and bottom spines to x = 0 and y = 0, respectively.
ax.spines["left"].set_position(("data", 0))
ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
```

By:

```
# Set the x and y starting tick to 0.
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_xlim(0)
```

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Set the x and y starting tick to 0.
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_xlim(0)
# Hide the top and right spines.
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

# Draw arrows (as black triangles: ">k"/"^k") at the end of the axes.  In each
# case, one of the coordinates (0) is a data coordinate (i.e., y = 0 or x = 0,
# respectively) and the other one (1) is an axes coordinate (i.e., at the very
# right/top of the axes).  Also, disable clipping (clip_on=False) as the marker
# actually spills out of the axes.
ax.plot(1, 0, ">k", transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.plot(0, 1, "^k", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)

# Some sample data.
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x*np.pi))

plt.show()
```