# How to add axis arrow tip for R plots

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw a plot in R that its x axis and y axis have an arrow in their tips. I googled it and did not found anything helpful. I found it how to do it in Python in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737736/matplotlib-axis-arrow-tip).
I want something like this picture:

[image]

**My attempt:**
I remove the plot frame and add axis separately.

```
x=seq(0,5,by=.1)
y=x*x
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, frame.plot = FALSE, type="l")
box(bty="l")
axis(1)
axis(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `Arrowhead` from package `shape` draws arrowhead-shaped polygons centered at user-supplied points. To draw arrowheads at the top left and bottom right corners of the plot region pointing in the direction of your axes, you can do:

```r
usr <- par("usr")
shape::Arrowhead(
  x0 = usr[1:2], 
  y0 = usr[4:3], 
  angle = c(90, 0), 
  xpd = TRUE
)
```

where `par("usr")` is a vector `c(left, right, bottom, top)` specifying the boundary of the plot region in user coordinates. `xpd = TRUE` ensures that arrowheads are not clipped to the plot region.

If you want to avoid installing a package, then note that base R has `arrows`, but it does not draw filled arrowheads *and* it complains if you ask for a zero-length arrow (i.e., an arrow with a head but no shaft). One way around the latter issue is to draw arrows that are collinear with the axes:

```r
usr <- par("usr")
arrows(
  x0 = usr[1L],
  x1 = usr[1:2], 
  y0 = usr[3L], 
  y1 = usr[4:3],
  length = 0.1,
  angle = 20,
  xpd = TRUE
)
```

As you might expect, both functions have optional arguments that you can use to adjust the appearance of the arrow(head)s.