# How to plot axes with arrows in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to achieve the following three things:

- add arrows on x and y axes
- show only the values that are used
- add labels for coordinates

My code on this moment:

```
x = [9, 8, 11, 11, 14, 13, 16, 14, 14]
y = [9, 16, 15, 11, 10, 11, 10, 8, 8]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7), dpi=300)
axes = fig.add_axes([0,1,1,1])

axes.set_xlim(0, 17)
axes.set_ylim(0, 17)

axes.invert_yaxis()

axes.scatter(x, y, color='green')
axes.vlines(x, 0, y, linestyle="dashed", color='green')
axes.hlines(y, 0, x, linestyle="dashed", color='green')
axes.spines.right.set_visible(False)
axes.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Visually:

[image]

And plot that I want to realize
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737736/matplotlib-axis-arrow-tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw arrows by overlaying triangle shaped points over the ends of your spines.

You'll need to leverage some [`transforms`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), but you can also create your labels by manually adding text to your `Axes` objects as well.

Labelling each coordinate can be done via [axes.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html), but you'll need to manually specify the location of each annotation to ensure they don't overlap with lines or other annotations.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

x = [9, 8, 11, 11, 14, 13, 16, 14, 14]
y = [9, 16, 15, 11, 10, 11, 10, 8, 8]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7), dpi=300)
axes = fig.add_axes([.05,.05,.9,.9])

# Plots the data
axes.scatter(x, y, color='green')
axes.vlines(x, 0, y, linestyle="dashed", color='green')
axes.hlines(y, 0, x, linestyle="dashed", color='green')

axes.set_xlim(0, 17)
axes.set_ylim(0, 17)
axes.set_xticks(x)
axes.set_yticks(y)
axes.invert_yaxis()

# Move ticks to top side of plot
axes.xaxis.set_tick_params(
    length=0, bottom=False, labelbottom=False, top=True, labeltop=True
)
axes.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)

# Add arrows to the spines by drawing triangle shaped points over them
axes.plot(1, 1, '>k', transform=axes.transAxes, clip_on=False)
axes.plot(0, 0, 'vk', transform=axes.transAxes, clip_on=False)
axes.spines[['bottom', 'right']].set_visible(False)

# Add labels for 0, F_1 and F_2
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy
axes.text(
    0, 1, s='0', fontstyle='italic', ha='right', va='bottom',
    transform=offset_copy(axes.transAxes, x=-5, y=5, fig=fig, units='points'),
)
axes.text(
    1, 1, s='$F_1$', fontstyle='italic', ha='right', va='bottom',
    transform=offset_copy(axes.transAxes, x=0, y=5, fig=fig, units='points'),
)
axes.text(
    0, 0, s='$F_2$', fontstyle='italic', ha='right',
    transform=offset_copy(axes.transAxes, x=-5, y=0, fig=fig, units='points'),
)

# Add labels at each point. Leveraging the alignment of the text
# AND padded offset.
lc = ('top', 'center', 0, -5)
ll = ('top', 'right', -5, -5)
lr = ('top', 'left', 5, -5)
ur = ('bottom', 'left', 5, 5)
alignments = [lc, lc, lc, ll, lc, ll, lc, ur, lr]
for i, (xc, yc, (va, ha, padx, pady)) in enumerate(zip(x, y, alignments)):
    axes.annotate(
        xy=(xc, yc), xytext=(padx, pady),
        text=f'$F(x_{i})$', ha=ha, va=va, textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
axes.plot(1, 0, ">k", transform=axes.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)  
axes.plot(0, 0, "vk", transform=axes.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
```

Will do it for you. This is basically just a cheat plot of markers.

---

There are also

`from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines.AxesZero`
which allow

```
for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
    # adds arrows at the ends of each axis
    ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
```

but they can't handle the reversed y axis in your case with default settings.