# How to add arrows next to axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hello I cant figure out how to add arrows next text axes labels. Do anyone know how to do it?
It should look somelike this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY5EE.png)

Here is my code:
I will appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300,100)
canvas = None

name_varX = tk.StringVar()
name_varY = tk.StringVar()

type_val_x = tk.StringVar()
nmb_curves = tk.IntVar()
nmb_varY = tk.IntVar()
valsY = tk.StringVar()
graph_name = tk.StringVar()



x = []
y = []


frame = tk.Frame(root)
label = tk.Label(text = "Graph creation tool")
label.config(font=("Arial", 15))
label.pack()


def enter_clicked():

    global y
    global x

    valsY1 = valsY.get()

    if not valsY1:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Nezadali jste naměřené hodnoty!')
    else:

        valsY1_list = valsY1.split(",")
        y = [float(valsY1_hodnota) for valsY1_hodnota in valsY1_list]
        nmb_varY = len(y)
        print(nmb_varY)
        print(y)

        type_val_x = type_val_x_combobox.get()
        if type_val_x == '0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ... ':
            print(valsY1)

            for m in range(0, nmb_varY):
                x.insert(m, (m+1) / 10)
                print(m + 1, ". hodnota na ose y je:", x[m])

        elif type_val_x == '1, 2, 3, 4 ...':
            for m in range(0, nmb_varY):
                x.insert(m, m+1)
                print(m + 1, ". hodnota na ose y je:", x[m])


        else:
            for i in range(0, nmb_varY):
                l = simpledialog.askfloat(title="INPUT", prompt="INPUT X")
                x.insert(i, l)
                print(i + 1, ". hodnota na ose y je:", x[i])
        print("hodnoty x:", x)


        name_varX1 = name_varX.get() if name_varX.get() == "" else f"${name_varX.get()}$"
        name_varY1 = name_varY.get() if name_varY.get() == "" else f"${name_varY.get()}$"

        global canvas

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()


        plt.plot(x,y, color='black', linestyle='dashdot', marker='x')
        plt.title(graph_name.get())
        plt.xlabel(name_varX1, loc='right', labelpad=0)
        plt.ylabel(name_varY1, loc='top', rotation='horizontal', labelpad=0)
        plt.xticks(x)
        plt.yticks(y)
        plt.grid()


        # Add arrows to both axes
        arrow_format = dict(facecolor='black', edgecolor='black', arrowstyle='->', shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0, linewidth=0.45, mutation_scale=25)
        ax.annotate('', xy=(1, 0), xytext=(0.95, 0), arrowprops=arrow_format, xycoords='axes fraction',
                    textcoords='axes fraction')
        ax.annotate('', xy=(0, 1), xytext=(0, 0.95), arrowprops=arrow_format, xycoords='axes fraction',
                    textcoords='axes fraction')
        ax.annotate('', xy=(0, 1), xytext=(0, 0.95), arrowprops=arrow_format, xycoords='axes fraction',
                    textcoords='axes fraction')



        if canvas: canvas.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


def download_clicked():
    path = "C:\\Users\\vanda\\PycharmProjects\\01"
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=path, defaultextension=".png", filetypes=[("PNG files", "*.png"), ("All files", "*.*")])
    print(f"Plot saved to: {file_path}")
    plt.savefig(file_path)


# Nazev grafu
graph_name_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Název grafu:")
graph_name_label.pack(expand=True)

graph_name_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=graph_name)
graph_name_entry.pack(expand=True)

# # Pocet krivek
# nmb_curves_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Počet křivek:")
# nmb_curves_label.pack(expand=True)

# nmb_curves_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=nmb_curves)
# nmb_curves_entry.pack(expand=True)

# Number of variables for Y axis
nmb_varY_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Naměřené hodnoty:")
nmb_varY_label.pack(expand=True)

nmb_varY_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=valsY)
nmb_varY_entry.pack(expand=True)

# Type of values X

type_val_x_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Hodnoty na ose x:")
type_val_x_label.pack(expand=True)

type_val_x_combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=type_val_x)
type_val_x_combobox['values'] = ('0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ... ', 'Vlastní', '1, 2, 3, 4 ...')
type_val_x_combobox['state'] = 'readonly'
type_val_x_combobox.current(0)
type_val_x_combobox.pack(expand=True)


# Variable for X axis
name_varX_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Popisek osy x:")
name_varX_label.pack(expand=True)

name_varX_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=name_varX)
name_varX_entry.pack(expand=True)


# Variable for Y axis
name_varY_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Popisek osy y:")
name_varY_label.pack(expand=True)

name_varY_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=name_varY)
name_varY_entry.pack(expand=True)


# Enter button
enter_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Vygenerovat graf", command=enter_clicked)
enter_button.pack(expand=True, pady=10)

# Download button
download_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Stáhnout", command=download_clicked)
download_button.pack(expand=True, pady=10)

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried adding another ax.annotate:

```
 ax.annotate('', xy=(0, 1), xytext=(0, 0.95), arrowprops=arrow_format, xycoords='axes fraction',
                    textcoords='axes fraction')
```

But I dont know how to position it the right way for my purpose.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib axis arrow tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737736/matplotlib-axis-arrow-tip)